# set up hornet node failed

Tags: iota-network

I follow the guide to set up a iota node,but when I call http://0.0.0.0:14265/api/v1/tips,I got error
error: {
code: "503",
message: "Service Unavailable, error: node is not synchronized: code=503, message=Service Unavailable"
}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which guide you followed, there are several on the net. If you are using the Hornet-node software: a good place to start is the official Wiki for Iota at https://wiki.iota.org/hornet/getting_started .

For the result of the tips call: the node has first to become synced before tips can be created. A node can only be synced if it has peers, either by enabling Autopeering in the config or add manually peers, e.g. by asking in the Iota Discord channel nodesharing at https://discord.com/channels/397872799483428865/398600007378272256

Comment: +1 enable autopeering. its probably disabled.